# ArcMap changing toolbars position?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, toolbar

I have a set of Arcmap map templates, the toolbars within them at one time where fixed in position. Now for whatever reason, every time I or another open the template the ordering of the toolbars has changed.

Any Idea how to fix this?

****Research****

May be related to this bug.

[Is ArcGIS Desktop still affected by stacked toolbars bug (NIM003161) when opening MXD on multi-monitor configurations?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1027/is-arcgis-desktop-arcmap-10-affected-by-the-stacked-toolbars-bug-nim003161-whe)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem on my PC with multiple monitors. This thread helped me work around the problem:

[GeoNet - Toolbars won't stay where I move them(!)](https://geonet.esri.com/message/143590#143590)

Here is the specific post from the above thread :

> So what I did was worked with one toolbar at a time.
>
> My procedure for fixing my toolbars:
>
> 1) Click Restore Down to see what toolbars move.
>
> 2) Click Maximize 3) Undock troubled toolbar and leave it floating
>
> 4) Click Restore Down, does it move? If not, place it where you want
>   it. If it does, you still have a problem and this workaround will not
>   work.
>
> 5) Click Maximize and Restore Down to test if toolbar moves (this is
>   where it stays put! awesome!)
>
> 6) Repeat steps 1-5 for all other toolbars, but I never tried to do
>   them all at once.Here is a screenshot of the settings needed in
>   Toolbars > Customize > Options tab

In my case, it was the "Advanced Editing" toolbar that was causing problems. Now I add it when I need it and then remove it as soon as I no longer need it.