# ArcMap Corrupting Map Templates?

Tags: arcmap

Yesterday ArcMap crashed and corrupted the toolbar layout of a map I used as model.

[image: Corrupted]

No TOC, the Menu bar is on the left, ... Nothing dramatic, so I replaced them to something that is more of my liking:

[image: Normal]

I saved, closed my map (to save the display in my Normal.mxt) and reopened the map. I was back at its corrupted "look"!

I deleted my Normal.mxt template. Open ArcMap, and it was ok. I added the toolbars I use the most, saved it and made a copy of my Normal.mxt.

If I open an new map, the display is fine. If I try to open any existing map (even one created a couple months ago), the display is "re-corrupted" but I know I was fine in that document.

I used a script to create 45 maps from the model mentioned earlier, so I expect to them to have the corrupted layout (didn't notice this before creating them). But I don't want to have to replace all my toolbars everytime I open a map I created before.

Never had that behavior before.

I look like it's the same question as ["ArcMap changing toolbars"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29220/arcmap-changing-toolbars), but I didn't find an answer there for me.

Comment: check your normal.mxt is not in a folder that is read-only.

Comment: No. That's not it...

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? I try to get a number of (custom) toolboxes to show up every time I start Arcmap, but that was way more complicated than I could ever expect!

Comment: No. I uninstalled ArcGIS 10.0 using "ArcGIS 10.1 Uninstall Utility" (which is supposed to remove everything) and every times I open a .mxd created in 10.0, my toolbar are all messed up. Toolbars are ok though when I create a new map in 10.1. Frustrating.

Comment: Maybe try MXD Doctor to repair the map?