# How to keep ArcMap Toolbar in a nice order?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, toolbar

I`m having an issue with my ArcMap. Every time I open it the tool bar is really messy, so I always have to start re-organising the tool bar first. Does anyone have an idea of how can I keep it in order without rearranging it every single time I use it?

Comment: What version of Arc are you using? Haven't encountered this myself.

Comment: The version I use is Arc 10.2

Comment: This info should be saved in your `Normal.mxd`. Try (1) deleting Normal.mxd, (2) open *one* instance of Arcmap, (3) rearrange your toolbar as to your preference, (4) close Arcmap. Then it should be saved to Normal.mxd and used as template for next time you open Arcmap.

Comment: If you are referring to multiple toolbars jumping around, or stacking themselves, this has been a long standing problem with ArcGIS from 9x to 10x. There have been a variety of solutions offered.  See https://geonet.esri.com/thread/96249 for some.  Also See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1027/is-arcgis-desktop-arcmap-10-affected-by-the-stacked-toolbars-bug-nim003161-whe

Comment: If your symptoms match those in the links that @johns has provided, then I think this is one for [Esri Support](http://support.esri.com).